# Trouble with calling prompts twice

Tags: javascript

I am having trouble with running a prompt twice. I do not know how to link the let statement at the bottom of the statement with var options = passwordOptions(); without running through the prompts twice.

```js
function generatePassword() {
  var options = passwordOptions();
  var result = []
  var possible = []
  var guaranteed = []
  var password = ""

  if(options.specialCharacters){
    possible = possible.concat(specChar)
    guaranteed.push(getRandom(specChar))
    password+= getRandom(specChar)
  }

  if(options.lowerCaseChar){
    possible = possible.concat(lowerCase)
    guaranteed.push(getRandom(lowerCase))
    password+= getRandom(lowerCase)
  }

  if(options.upperCaseChar){
    possible = possible.concat(upperCase)
    guaranteed.push(getRandom(upperCase))
    password+= getRandom(upperCase)
  }

  if(options.numChar){
    possible = possible.concat(numbers)
    guaranteed.push(getRandom(numbers))
    password+= getRandom(upperCase)
  }


  let passwordLength = passwordOptions().passwordLength
  while(password.length < passwordLength) {
    password+=guaranteed[Math.floor(Math.random() * guaranteed.length)]
  }
  return password;
}

function getRandom(arr) {
  var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)
  var randomElement = arr[randomIndex]

  
  return randomElement;
}
```

Comment: You assign the return value of `passwordOptions()` to `options` at the start of `generatePassword`, but `passwordOptions()` is called again towards the end of the function in order to obtain the length. Why not `passwordLength = options.length`?

Comment: Thank you, I ended up going with  let passwordLength = options.passwordLength and that fixed the issue